# How to provide same parameter for multiple nodes using parameter file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was writing a parameter file for multiple nodes and was wondering if I can pass the same parameter for multiple nodes without me specifically mentioning it in the parameters list of each node.
like

```
lidar_data:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"
    

gpio_reader:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"
    

gpio_writer:
  ros__parameters:
    robot_name: "BOT02/"
```

Over here I have passed robot_name to each node and in the future, if I want to change the name I have to replace it for each node. Is there something like declaring on the top of the parameter file like we do with packages and that variable is passed on wherever is required?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403793/how-to-provide-same-parameter-for-multiple-nodes-using-parameter-file/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out this: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-ROS2-Launch-For-Large-Projects.html#using-wildcards-in-yaml-files

---

Originally posted by [BlakeAnderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/110453/blakeanderson/) with karma: 66 on 2022-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1